# How to make Nested Aggregations under parent's datetime histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, histogram

I'm following this example inside officle doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "comments": { 
      "nested": {
        "path": "comments"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_month": {
          "date_histogram": { 
            "field":    "comments.date",
            "interval": "month",
            "format":   "yyyy-MM"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_stars": {
              "avg": { 
                "field": "comments.stars"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

question is: I need make date_histogram with blogpost's date, but not comments date:

```
 "field":    "comments.date",
```

to :

```
 "field":    "date",
```

and as of the **"nested"** above this histogram aggs, so this modification didn't work, How to make this work out?

Thanks!

Comment: Well,...I see, I should make a **reverse_nested** ... , then I need figure out how to make this work under .NET NEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible in NEST yet:

From the nest website:

> A special single bucket aggregation that enables aggregating on parent
>   docs from nested documents.
>
> Not implemented yet

https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/aggregations/reverse-nested.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some document search later, and .NET NEST can work on this question: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-histogram-aggregation-usage.html

and here are some clue on [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/357), maybe help someone else.